# IlligileMonitorStateException

Tags: java, exception

```
class A
{
    synchronized void m1()
    {   
        try
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"inside m1");
            notify();
            DeadlockAvoidance.a2.wait();
            DeadlockAvoidance.a2.m2();
        }
        catch(IllegalMonitorStateException e)
        {
            //System.out.println("IllegalMonitorStateException occured");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            //System.out.println("IllegalMonitorStateException occured");
        }
    }

    synchronized void m2()
    {   
        try
        {   
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"inside m2");
            notify();
            DeadlockAvoidance.a1.wait();
            DeadlockAvoidance.a1.m1();
        }
        catch(IllegalMonitorStateException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IllegalMonitorStateException occured");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IllegalMonitorStateException occured");
        }
    }
}

class DeadlockAvoidance
{
    static A a1=new A();
    static A a2=new A();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Main is running");

        Runnable r1=new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        a1.m1();
                                    }
                                };

        Runnable r2=new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        a2.m2();
                                    }
                                };

        Thread t1=new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2=new Thread(r2);

        t1.setName("Thread-1");
        t2.setName("Thread-2");

        System.out.println("Thread 1 created");
        System.out.println("Thread 2 created");
        t1.start();t2.start();

        System.out.println("main() finished...!!!");
    }
}
```

================================================================

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\src\Day13>java DeadlockAvoidance
Main is running
Thread 1 created
Thread 2 created
main() finished...!!!
Thread-2inside m2
Thread-1inside m1
IllegalMonitorStateException occured

## IllegalMonitorStateException occured

kindly help me to fix this exception....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please read the rules for on-topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Rule 1 states **"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."**

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) the documentation of `wait()` method, this is what it says:

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.
>
> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of
>   this object's monitor. See the notify method for a description of the
>   ways in which a thread can become the owner of a monitor.

So, in order to call `wait()` on an object, you must require the `monitor` for that object, you can acquire the monitor by calling the `wait()` from inside the `synchronized` context.

The example in the question is calling `wait()` on `a1` and `a2` instances whereas they have acquired the lock on **current** instance (and not a1 or a2).

E.g. In order to call `wait()` on `a2`, we need to write the following:

```
synchronized(a2){
    DeadlockAvoidance.a2.wait();
}
```

As the thread does not hold the lock on a1 or a2 while calling `wait()`, `IllegalMonitorStateException` gets thrown.

Comment: Thank you buddy.... As per ur gyidance i have made changes but I'm still facing the same exception.... Firstly it was throwing exception two time...... After making changes suggested by you it is throwing exception now for one time only need some more help

Comment: Thank you, for your assistance.